# Find Specific Element on Japanese Website via Selenium or BeautifulSoup on Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I want to find a specific element on a Japanese real estate website via Selenium or BeautifulSoup.

The website URL, with the specifications I set, is:
`CHINTAI_URL = "https://www.chintai.net/list/?cf=0&ct=70&jk=0&jl=0&sf=0&st=0&b=1&b=2&b=3&h=99&j=6&k=1&st=0&ue=000013609&ue=000000849&ue=000006985&prefkey=ibaragi&&rt=51&o=10&p=100&"`

The python code I have written is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "C:\Development\chromedriver.exe"

#chintai.net selenium start

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(CHINTAI_URL)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)


address_content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div div.cassette_txt ul li:nth-child(2)')
  #div > div.cassette_txt > ul > li:nth-child(2)

for element in address_content:
    text = element.text
    print(text)

address_content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.cassette_inner div.bukken_information table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)')

for element in address_content:
    text = element.text
    print(text)

#searchInputForm > div.l_cassette > section:nth-child(8) > div.cassette_inner > div.bukken_information > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)
#//[@id="searchInputForm"]/div[2]/section[4]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()
#//[@id="searchInputForm"]/div[2]/section[5]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()
```

Incidentally, the first loop for the first three results on the website does exactly what I want: Just the address of the property on the site. The second for loop however, for the fourth and later properties, gives me the the property address, as well as the text of the map displayed right under the address text.

I tried CSS Selectors, Xpaths, Name Tags, Class Names, everything. And so, at last, I came here to ask for help :D In my case, the address of the 4th property I see is: 茨城県取手市新町５丁目

As said above, I simply want the address text for the fourth and following property listings on the website. If there is an easier way to do this with BeautifulSoup, then gladly. I tried that, too, and it didn't work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: The problem is that the structure is different for the 3 first houses

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think is like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#Define web driver as a Chrome driver and navigate
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://www.chintai.net/list/?cf=0&ct=70&jk=0&jl=0&sf=0&st=0&b=1&b=2&b=3&h=99&j=6&k=1&st=0&ue=000013609&ue=000000849&ue=000006985&prefkey=ibaragi&&rt=51&o=10&p=100&'
driver.get(url)


# This function will receive an element, and from that element will search all the subelements and will delete the text of those subelements and will only return the text of the main element, which is the one we want
def remove_subelements_texts(element):
    element_text = element.text
    subelements = element.find_elements(By.XPATH, './*')
    for subelement in subelements:
        element_text = element_text.replace(subelement.text, "").strip()
    return element_text


# Save all the houses in a list, only the not recommended ones, the recommended ones have different class, so you should investigate how to do it, this case is the not recommended ones
houses = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='l_cassette']/section[@class='cassette_item build'])")))


# Then with that list we will get the H2 (title), the first cell of table (address) and third cell of table (construction year) for every house
for i in range(1, len(houses)+1):
    # We save the title element
    title_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//section[@class='cassette_item build'])[{i}]//h2")))
    # We could take the text of title, but it contains also the text of subelements, in this case the text of sublements is "Rental apartment" or something like that. We dont care that text, so we remove it
    title_text = remove_subelements_texts(element=title_element)
    # We save the address element
    address_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"((//section[@class='cassette_item build'])[{i}]//td)[1]")))
    # We could take the text of title, but it contains also the text of subelements, in this case the text of sublements is the MAP information, we dont care that map text, so we remove it.
    address_text = remove_subelements_texts(element=address_element)
    # Same with construction year and we can continue with all of them
    construction_year_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"((//section[@class='cassette_item build'])[{i}]//td)[3]")))
    construction_year_text = remove_subelements_texts(element=construction_year_element)
    print(title_text)
    print(address_text)
    print(construction_year_text)
```

Your main problem was, as you can see that your element (Address) contained several subelements and those subelements had also text, so when you did `.text` you were getting the text from subelements, so you need to remove those subelements text

Comment: Holy, wow! Thank you so much! I'll have a good read through the code and then tackle the link address leading to the detailed description of the property and the rent price. The end goal is to feed that data to a google form for a pretty spreadsheet, but that should be doable (famous last words). Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure mate! I Hope It helps!

Comment: @Etoluz please could you mark answer as accepted if it was  what you wanted? Thank you!